# Start function with both mousewheel and doubleclick jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that starts like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#map').bind('mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
```

The function starts when I scroll with my mouse, how do I do if I also want to execute this function with doubleclick? So that the user can choose himself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but you won't have `delta` available for `dblclick` event.

```
$('#map').bind('mousewheel dblclick', function(e, delta) {
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Is there any simple way to check if the user double clicked or if he scrolled?

Comment: i think when `dblclick` will trigger `delta` will be `undefined`, so `if (delta)` block will executed only on scroll.

Comment: @Daniel, e.originalEvent will give you the information.  I use chrome's console.log to see object details.  Makes development much easier: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/pSL4B/

Answer (score 0):

you should try separate functions and events like this :

```
function map_event(e, delta){
  ...
}

$("#map").scroll(map_event);
$("#map").dblclick(map_event);
```